# How to change the font color of popup in haskell layer

Tags: spacemacs, fonts, themes

I am not good at emacs because using spacemacs only for haskell coding.
I want to change the font color of popup from white to black. White text on yellow popup is too hard to read.
It's solarized dark theme and haskell-layer.

Please let me know how to change this font color.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer from [spacemacs issue](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/11541). It's because of Mac OSX's dark theme and can be resolved by below command

```
defaults write org.gnu.Emacs NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance true
```